# How to plot a graph with labels that don't superimpose on each others

Tags: r, plot, label, igraph

I am new at R but I haven't find any topic that could answer my question.

I want to plot a graph named g, using the package igraph. However the result is not fully satisfying as the nodes names aren't all readable.

This is the code I used to plot :

```
plot(g, layout_nicely(g), asp=FALSE, vertex.shape=V(g)$shape, vertex.label.dist=0.3,
 vertex.label.degree=-pi/2)
```

[And this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucswN.png)

I've tried to reduce the number of characters of each label, or to reduce their font sizes but it wasn't enough. I also used several layout such as layout.kamada.kawai, layout.fruchterman.reingold but the labels are always too close to each others. 
Is there any way to choose a better position for the labels or to increase the length of the edges ?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you give some example data?

Comment: @RuthgerRighart I use a symetric matrix with numbers between 0 and 1 (a correlation matrix) and then I create a graph adjacency with this two lines of code : `ga=graph.adjacency(Dis_mat,mode=c("undirected"),weighted=TRUE)                   g=minimum.spanning.tree(ga,algorithm="prim")`